# Text view display issue

Tags: android, layout, android-inflate

I am inflating **item_horizontal.xml** in following class. I am able to see the background colors #7000 but unable to see value of text view.

**HorizontalLayoutItemLayout.java**

```
public class HorizontalLayoutItemLayout extends FrameLayout {


    public HorizontalLayoutItemLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public HorizontalLayoutItemLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public HorizontalLayoutItemLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        mView = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_horizontal,this,false);

        addView(mView);
}
```

**item_horizontal.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="#7000"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

   <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="456"
    android:textColor="@color/selector_rise_fall_isenable"
    android:textSize="17sp" >
   </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post the output of the command `adb shell dumpsys activity top`

Comment: i post the code @pskink

Comment: it is cut off on the right (not complete)

Comment: i cut the picture in the answer @pskink

Comment: What is the value of @color/selector_rise_fall_isenable?